# Spring data jpa - DUPLICATE row was found and Assert was specified

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I'm using spring data jpa @EmbeddedId for my child table BookId which has composite primary on two columns. I'm able to insert and get the records without any issue but when I try to update the existing record I'm getting duplicate row exception. Same code was working fine with spring boot 2.x but I recently upgraded to spring boot 3.x issue started popping out

```
@Data

@Embeddable

public class BookId implements Serializable {

    @ManyToOne

    @JoinColumn(name="author", nullable=false)

    private Author author;

    @Column(name="name")

    private String name;

    // standard getters and setters

}

@Data

@Entity(name="T_BOOK")

public class Book {

    @EmbeddedId

    private BookId id;

    @Column(name="genre")

    private String genre;

    @Column(name="price")

    private Integer price;

    //standard getters and setters


}
```

When I use below code to update already existing record getting duplicate row error

bookRepository.save(book)

Comment: why are you using `save` method as update method ?

Comment: More constructively: `save` is for new rows, `update` is for updates.

Comment: @AndreiLisa data jpa repository does not have update method instead save method does both save or update if id value exists. Please read data jpa documentation for more info

Comment: be sure I know it,  in your case the problem that you have can be in equals and hashcode, you should override it and don’t use from Lombok default one. Also do you pass the id when you are going to update the existing one entity with ‘save’ method ?

Comment: @AndreiLisa You sure about that? hashCode and equals sure as shit didn't do anything for me